# Keycloak javascript adapter `keycloak.init` load 404 iframe

Tags: javascript, keycloak

I am trying to integrate Keycloak for my client side application using javascript adapter `keycloak-js`.

However, I can't seem to make it work. This is my code

```
const keycloak = new Keycloak({
    realm: 'my-realm',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/',
    clientId: 'my-client',
});

try {
    const authenticated = await keycloak.init();
    console.log(authenticated);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

It doesn't return anything, not even error or anything from the callback. I only have
`GET http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html 404 (Not Found)`
Not sure what did I do wrong? I follow the documentation but I can't find anything about this behaviour
If I type the url above in browser, I see this

[image]

Is there anything I can do?

**EDIT:** I managed to make it work using this code by matching keycloak server with keycloak-js version. **Upgrading server and keycloak-js version to 11.0.2 does work for me as well as downgrading both version to 10.0.2**

This is the client configuration that I'm using
[image]

In the code example above, I can see `console.log(isAuthorised);` return `false` in dev tools, and if I do `const isAuthorised = await keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' });`, It will redirect me to login page and redirect me back to this page after successful login. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably a version mismatch between `keycloak-js` and your keycloak server. I was using the newest `keycloak-js` version `11.0.0` with a keycloak server version of `10.0.1`, which lead to this exact error. Downgrading `keycloak-js` on the client side to `10.0.2` did the trick for me. (Haven't tried to upgrade the keycloak server yet, but most likely works as well)

Comment: Hi, that is exactly what happened. Thanks!
Didn't realise the newer version has just released last week, this made me a bit crazy

Comment: you need to match the keycloak server version and keycloak-js version on client @MatthewDolman

Comment: yes, but server 11.0.2 and keycloak-js 11.0.0.2 still doesn't work

Comment: Same here with 11.0.2 client AND server.

Comment: I ran into the same problem with 11.0.2 client and server. Any solutions? Except downgrading to 10.x?

Comment: Odd, it does work for me though. I've added my client configuration in the question in case it helps

Comment: same with 12.0.2

Comment: Same here with 12.0.3, this is really annoying, documentation is very sparse on how this works

Comment: I was able to solve the issue in Keycloak v14.0 by adding /auth/ to the URL in the Keycloak js adapter config (eg. https://localhost:8080/auth/)