# Gatsby Keycloak integration

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, keycloak

I'm having issues trying to integrate Keycloak with a Gatsby static website.
The purpose of the integration is letting logged users interact with components in the website (features such as: Like, Share, etc.), while the website is completely public.

The Keycloak instance is on a remote server, with the realm set-up and the client added with this [configuration](https://pastebin.com/rGa2TXVf).

I'm using [this repo](https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak-examples/tree/master/examples/gatsbyjs) as reference, but I guess there are some differences because of the modules version. I'm using:

```
"@react-keycloak/web": "^2.1.3",
"keycloak-js": "^11.0.0",
```

Here's my gatsby-browser.js:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { node } from 'prop-types'
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js'
import { KeycloakProvider } from '@react-keycloak/web'

const keycloak = new Keycloak({
  realm: 'myRealm',
  url: 'https://myKeycloak.com/auth',
  clientId: 'myClientId'
})

const Loading = () => <div>getting ready...</div>

const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <KeycloakProvider
      keycloak={keycloak}
      initConfig={{
        promiseType: 'native',
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
          window.location.origin + '/silent-check-sso.xhtml'
      }}
      LoadingComponent={<Loading />}
    >
      {element}
    </KeycloakProvider>
  )
}

wrapRootElement.propTypes = {
  element: node
}

const _wrapRootElement = wrapRootElement
export { _wrapRootElement as wrapRootElement }
```

I'm getting stuck in the `getting ready...` page, while on the network tools I get:

```
GET https://myKeycloak.com/auth/realms/myRealm/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html
Status 404
Not Found
```

Do you have any tip for me?
Thanks in advance, have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to the Keycloak configuration, there's the solution I found for my case:

- Create Realm;
- Add a client;
- Enter Root URL (root page of your gatsby website);
- Enter Admin URL (administration page of your gatsby website);
- Enter Web Origins

With that configuration, the above gatsby-browser file works for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the latest `keycloak-js` version is not compatible with older Keycloak servers. Try downgrading `keycloak-js` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63103132/14170399). Version `10.0.2` did the trick for me.